# Regex for domains with protocols Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have written Python script which loops through txt file and it is trying to find domain in every line.

requirements for regex:

- contain protocols such as http, https, www, etc.
- contain "-" for example, ab-cd.com
- contain numbers, letters, other characters, case insensitive
- contain URL for example, ab.com/home

Regex for this is -> `r"(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]"`
But I want also find domains with protocols (http, https, www, etc.)

I tried something like this -> `r"https://www\.|http://www\.|https://www|http://|https://|www\.|http."`

The point is, I am not able to merge those two.
I am new to regex so if above lines of existing regex is wrong or could be better, I will be glad for your answer.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the txt file? hopefully with different cases `http://example.com`, `www.example-a.com`, `https://www.example.org`

Comment: Hello, something like this: example.com |example.com |http:/example.com |https:/example.site |example.site |www.example-a.org |www.example-a.org/home |Example.tyz |ex.ample.com |example.web.id |example.org/exmp.exe

Comment: For *domain name* use `(?:xn--|)(?![^.]*--)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]\.[a-z]{2,}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) must follow some rules for it to be valid. The following regex just assumes a domain is valid if its top-level domain is only lower case letters.

```
import re
pat = r'(?:https?)?(?::\/\/)?[\w\.-]+\.(?:[a-z]+)(?:\/[\w\.\/]*)*'
inpt = 'Hello, something like this: example.com |example.com |http://example.com |http:/example.com |https://example.site |example.site |www.example-a.org |www.example-a.org/home |Example.tyz |ex.ample.com |example.web.id |example.org/exmp.exe'
matches = re.findall(pat, inpt)

print(*matches, sep='\n')
```

Output

```
example.com
example.com
http://example.com
example.com
https://example.site
example.site
www.example-a.org
www.example-a.org/home
Example.tyz
ex.ample.com
example.web.id
example.org/exmp.exe
```

You can test it with [this pattern in regexr.com](https://regexr.com/5bfvv)

---

You could also try with a different group for the `path` part of the url, and allow for any character other than space (again, not according to url format rules but, works for the case).

```
pat = r'(?:https?)?(?::\/\/)?[\w\.-]+\.(?:[a-z]+)(?:\/[\S]*)*'
```

Comment: It is possible to include those types as well? Not to specifically use only "com|net|org|web" but lets say characters from 2 to 10 (count of characters)?